# Issues in texturing

Tags: texturing

I am having a character in .fbx format. While opening the same in blender, I am facing some texturing issues. Both the Screenshots for The character what it should look originally and the same what is appearing in blender are attached.

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you please share a part of your character, like the pants, or at least show a screenshot of the material?

Comment: Hello @moonboots . Could you please send me your mail id? So that I can send you the fbx file of the character?

Comment: Better share the file if it is not a paid model and you don't mind sharing it publicly. Sadly pasteall.org is gone but you can share it on google drive, dropbox, or https://wetransfer.com (in the menu you can create a direct link to the file and share the link here)

Comment: @Blunder ,actually this model is a paid one. That's why I am finding some alternatives to share this model privately.

Comment: That's okay. BSE is a Question & Answer site, it's not like a common forum. So asking someone for their mail address to help you makes your question a bad one because it does not help other people with a similar problem in the future. If you can't share the file add a few screenshots. If the model is black there is probably something wrong with the material or the shader nodes. What does the material look like?

Comment: Yeah you are right @Blunder . Actually my primary concern was not to avoid sharing the paid model rather my concern was to avoid complexities of copyright infringement of the source from where I have purchased the model. However, lastly I thought since I am not reselling the model and asking for help only in a community like Blender Stack Exchange, hence, the question of Copyright infringement will not appear. Moreover, sharing the whole model will help to address the issue fully rather sharing some screenshots. I am sharing Google drive link of the character for your needful please.

Answer (score 1):

It appears black because it is the color of the *Image Texture* (called *Bitmaptexture.001*) of the material (called *Material #2184*) that has been assigned to all these parts.

It looks like you should rather give the material called *07 - Default* to the pullover, because it has the blue image texture, and you should rather give the material called *Material #2313* to the pants, because it has the grey jeans texture.

The problem being that the UV map doesn't match, and that the image textures are not tileable (?), so you'll need to fix that. You'll probably need to load 2 new image textures, I don't understand how you're supposed to use the current image textures for the pullover and pants (*Map #4* and *Map #2070303786*).